Bottom sheet keep changing position when interact with an object in the background
i have an aplication which i plan to make it looks like a google maps apps, now i have bottomSheetBehaviour on the front and map in the background.
Whenever im interact with a background object (maps) the bottom sheet just got lower in snap movement (without animation) and also on start and after interact with the bottom sheet the COLLAPSE State is changing, like the peeking height just change or something.
the change is like , on start 550dp -> touch bottom sheet 600dp -> touch background 550dp -> touch bottom sheet 600dp. it's like when im interact with the bottom sheet the sheet is update or something
Here is the code
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MapView mapView;
    private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });

        Configuration.getInstance().load(this, getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE));
        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);

        IMapController mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(17);
        GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(  -5.14861000 , 119.43194000); // Contoh koordinat (Makassar)
        mapController.setCenter(startPoint);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
        }

//  DEKLARASI
        View bottomSheetViewIm3 = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_im3);
        View bottomSheetView3id = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_3id);
        View bottomSheetDashboard = findViewById(R.id.Dashboard_Overview);

        Button showBottomSheetButtonim3 = findViewById(R.id.butt_test_im3);
        Button showBottomSheetButton3id = findViewById(R.id.butt_test_3id);
        Button closeButton = findViewById(R.id.butt_test_close);


        behaviorIm3.setHideable(true);
        behavior3id.setHideable(true);
        behaviorDash.setHideable(false);
        

        behaviorIm3.setPeekHeight(1255);
        behavior3id.setPeekHeight(1255);
        behaviorDash.setPeekHeight(550);

        behaviorIm3.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
        behavior3id.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
        behaviorDash.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);


        showBottomSheetButtonim3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(behavior3id.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED || behavior3id.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED){
                    behavior3id.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
                }
                behaviorDash.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
                behaviorIm3.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            }
        });

        showBottomSheetButton3id.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(behaviorIm3.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED || behaviorIm3.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED){
                    behaviorIm3.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
                }
                behaviorDash.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
                behavior3id.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            }
        });

        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (behaviorIm3.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED ||
                        behavior3id.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED ||
                        behaviorIm3.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED ||
                        behavior3id.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                    behaviorIm3.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
                    behavior3id.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

Help me find a solution or recomendation on how to do it in a different way
